# Does Admob (with SKAdNetwork support) still do data collection (with regards to App privacy details on the App Store)?

Tags: ios, admob, google-mobile-ads, skadnetwork

With Apple's latest announcement on 5 November 2020 for developers to provide information about their app's privacy practices, I was wondering if with the latest Google Mobile Ads SDK, do I still need to disclose "Third-party partners" such as advertising networks? I mean we are using SKAdNetwork (Apple's own API), right? Does my situation fall under "Optional disclosure"?

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/